# How do you initialize a FormCollection with Files in .NET?

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible to initialize `Formcollection` with Files?

The constructor is

```
public FormCollection(Dictionary<string, StringValues> fields, IFormFileCollection files = null);
```

The code:

```
var formCol = new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues>
 {
   { "Validate", "True" },
   { "Field2", "String Value 2" },
   { "Field3", "String Value 3" }
 });
```

creates `FormCollection` but the file count is 0(as expected).
I am trying to add `IFormFileCollection`, but I see there are no setters in the interface/class.

Any help to add files in form collection will be useful.

Comment: You can't. `FormCollection` is for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` submissions, which cannot contain files. HTML form file uploads use `multipart/form-data` which is represented with a different type in ASP.NET (but I forget which, sorry)

Comment: could you show the whole picture of your issue? why do you need to add an item to that collection manually? usually we just need to care about its value which is bound by `model binding`, the files are sent from the client. Adding files to the collection on the server side makes no sense to me, never seen such a scenario.

Comment: @KingKing I have a azure function which uploads files to blob storage. I have tested the function using postman., where I pass the file in post body type form-data. Now I am  trying to come up with a functional test, where I am constructing the HttpRequest with the file in post body (as form data) and firing the post request to test the azure function.The idea behind this test is to have it CI/CD pipeline to run tests before every deployment.